# Is this possible with Zend Framework and CKEditor

Tags: zend-framework

Hope someone can help me, i am storing php in a table stored as a text field in my database as:

```
<?php
    echo "this is a test";
?>
```

And i am pulling this content out of the database to be rendered using the below command in the preDispatch function of a controller:-

```
<?php
    class Ajfit_Controller_View_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action {

         public function preDispatch()
         {
            parent::preDispatch();

            $this->getResponse()->setBody($page->getContent());
         }
    }
?>
```

My problem is the when i render the content from the database the page just displays the text of the php and does not execute it, is what I am doing even possible?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use eval($phpcode) for that to work.  It's a security risk if you were to accept this from untrustworthy sources.

You will also have to add:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

so that ZF doesn't try to render the view.

if you decide to use eval(), you might want to do this:

```
ob_start();
eval(preg_replace("/^<\?(php)?(.*)\?>$/", '$2', $page->getContent()));
$body = ob_get_clean();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($body);
```

You cannot have the eval'd content wrapped in open/close PHP tags, hence the preg_replace.

Comment: @Mattew Scragg Thanks for your response, and i already added $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(); thanks mate, However now i get this error 
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AJF-IT\library\Ajfit\Controller\View\Action.php(56) : eval()'d code on line 1  any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to remove the open/close php tags.

Comment: @Andrew'lionel'Fenna Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have changed the code as above and still the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in .... still happends, hmmm any ideas?

Comment: @Andrew'lionel'Fenna I would try to manually remove the php tags in the eval'd code to isolate the problem.  I still think that is why there is a parse error.  Also make sure to use a simple example.  A syntax error is hard to debug inside of eval().  Any trailing or leading whitespace in the eval'd code would cause my regex to not work as well.

Comment: i've manually stripped out the php tags and i've got a little further now its erroring on with this error:- Message: Method dialogContainer does not exist and was not trapped in __call() Stack 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\AJF-IT\library\Ajfit\Controller\View\Action.php(56) : eval()'d code(28): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('dialogContainer', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\AJF-IT\library\Ajfit\Controller\View\Action.php(56) : eval()'d code(28): Ajfit_IndexController->dialogContainer('dialog', Object(Ajfit\Form\User\Login), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\AJF-IT\library\Ajfit\Controller\View\Action.php(56): eval()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8023/discussion-between-andrew-lionel-fenna-and-matthew-scragg)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to run it through PHP's `eval` function, but this has **tremendous** potential security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not architect your application like this. If you need your code used in multiple places, look at something like rsync:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync